# Hibernate get remaining objects from many to one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a database which stores clubs and teams.
A club has multiple teams and a team is part of only one club.
Is it possible to query all teams which are not in a specific club using
the hibernate criteria api?
Here are the (stripped) Club.java and Team.java

**Club.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clubs")
public class Club {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "club_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club")
    private java.util.Set<Team> teams;

    [setters, constructors etc]
}
```

**Team.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "team_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "club_id")
    private Club club;

    [same here]   
}
```

Comment: Could you share some existing code with us? JPA model objects would be very useful.

Comment: I edited my post, thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a slight variation on the answer above, if you already have the Club object which you wish to find all teams not belonging to it, you should be able to do something like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Team.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("club", myClub));
List<Team> teams = criteria.list();
```

This avoids having to query on the club name and IMHO is cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Team.class);
        .createAlias("club", "c")
        .add( Restrictions.not(Restrictions.like("c.name", "nameOfTheClubIAmLookingFor", MatchMode.EXACT)) )
        List<Team> teams=criteria.list();
```